# Change text during jQuery Highlight effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, highlight

Is there any way of changing the text of a div whilst a highlighting effect is taking place, and then revert back to the original text once it has finished?

Code for initiating the highlight effect:

```
$("#myDiv").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Comment: u mean about what text property

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. Change the text value e.g. Change from 'Show Basket' to 'Item Added' whilst the effect is on

Comment: can't u add a complete function to the .effect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
   var myDiv=$("#myDiv");
    myDiv.data("old",myDiv.html());
    myDiv.html("New text");
    myDiv.effect("highlight", {}, 3000, callback);

    function callback(){
        var myDiv=$("#myDiv");
        myDiv.html(myDiv.data("old"));
    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aYm4f/1/)**

Comment: You can make your code better by caching and chaining method :)

Comment: Please, use chaining... or at least `var myDiv = $('#myDiv'); myDiv.data(...; myDiv.html(...`

Comment: updated answer. I personlaay dont like chaining cause many time that reduces readability.